# Interpreting physical conditions for heat or wave equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have my PDEs final this week, and my prof really likes giving us word problems and having us interpret the physical situation into the boundary conditions.

I wanted to confirm the following:

*Wave equation*

Displacement is given by $u(x,0)$

Velocity is given by $u_t(x,0)$

What are $u_x(x,0)$ and $u_x(x,L)$?

---

*Heat equation*

Initial temperature is given by $u(x,0)$

What about $u(x,L)$?

What does $u_x(x,0)$ represent?  What about $u_x(x,L)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I will not give a write up solution. I think you should check your textbook or think yourself. I am a PDE instructor this semester, and I am quite confident this should be in a standard undergraduate PDE textbook.

Comment: This isn't a homework question.  I'm just confused about how to interpret the physical conditions.  My class doesn't have a textbook and I've only been able to find some of them online... The ones I came up with I figured out by myself.  I legitimately just want to know this for my final.